# Запуск c++ программ на gpu [Intel Graphics 5500]

Tags: c++, gpu, parallel

*Пишу простенький рейтрейсинг, столкнулся с тем, что картинку с разрешением больше 25х25 в реалтайме отрисовывать не выходит*

Формально: имеется код вида

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        trace(x, y);
    }
}
```

Для каждой пары (x; y) функция `trace` вызывается независимо. Значит, по идее, можно исполнение кода распараллелить и запустить на gpu для большей скорости.

Вопрос заключается в одном - как? Какие библиотеки использовать, что гуглить?

Пока нашел вариант с использованием cuda, но программирую сейчас на ноуте с Intel Graphics 5500. Есть ли у меня возможность как-то использовать gpu? Чем проще будут предложения, тем лучше, потому что сталкиваюсь с подобной задачей впервые.

Если на Intel Graphic 5500 нельзя, то, предположим, найду видеокарту с поддержкой cuda. Тогда стоит использовать cuda + thrust?